# Language icon selector bug with webforms, fix or alternative?

Tags: webforms, i18n-l10n

i have installed a few modules for internationalization support, like:

- i18n
- i10n
- icons
- lang_dropdown
- i18n_string
- i18n_field
- entity translation
- webform_localization

The issue is relative to webform content, i have several pages where the language selector block i put left to menu works with a dropdown with the language as wanted.

But when i'm in the webform, it should show 2 languages but only shows the default one, how do i fix it?, is it a bug in webform_localization or in language icons or lang_dropdown?